# Как в AutoCompleteTextView вводить несколько слов с автодополнением

Tags: java, android

Есть данные типо

```
String asd[]={"A","B","C","AAA","BBB","CCC"};
```

Я добавил их в адаптер и адаптер в `AutoCompleteTextView`

Если ввести символ то появиться выбор. Но беда в том что я хочу добавить несколько слов. Чтобы было как то так. A,BBB,AAA. Но когда я ввожу символ, то проверка на свопадение слов перестает работать потому что в словаре нет строки типо "A,".

Как быть?

Comment: @pavlofff, Скажите откуда вы такой умный взялись?

Что за статьи или золотую книгу вы читаете что знаете обо всех компонентах? Дайте мне эту книжку пжлста)

Comment: вот [здесь](https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html) все написано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы можно было вводить несколько слов через разделитель с автодополнением каждого, нужно использовать виджет [`MultiAutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.html).

Пример:

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] {"Belgium", "France", "Italy", "Germany", "Spain"};


ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.edit);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
textView.setTokenizer(new MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer());
```

Виджету необходимо устанвить разделитель методом `setTokenizer()`, который будет разделять вводимые с автодополнением слова. В примере разделителем выступает уже готовый класс-разделитель "запятая" - [`CommaTokenizer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/MultiAutoCompleteTextView.CommaTokenizer.html)

Если запятая в качестве разделителя не устраивает, можно написать свой класс с необходимым разделителем (для примера ";"):

```
public static class SemicolonTokenizer implements Tokenizer {
    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ';') {
            i--;
        }
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }
    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();
        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ';') {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
        return len;
    }
    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();
        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            i--;
        }
        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ';') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + "; ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text + "; ";
            }
    }
```

и затем указать в качестве разделителя:

```
textView.setTokenizer(new SemicolonTokenizer());
```

Comment: Спс но я давно уже нашел ответ)). Как раз на Android сайте. Когда добавят возможность закрыть тему если ответ найден уже?

Comment: @xTIGRx Цель этого ресурса - база знаний для многих людей, а не личные консультации. Если вопрос и ответ качественные, их не нужно закрывать, решением сможет воспользоваться еще множество человек, кроме вас.

Comment: А зачем тогда мне давать ссылку на https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html.

А другим людям вы даете полный ответ?

Ведь я по ссылке https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html вполне нашел ответ на свой вопрос. Вы сами себе противоречите

Comment: @xTIGRx Вы спросили, где я все узнаю, я вам показал где. Не вижу связи между существованием офф.сайта разработчика и этим ответом.